# Blender Rigid Body Physics issue

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision, rigidbody

I want some balls to fall into holes with gravity but the balls pass without falling into the holes.  [image]

Comment: Please add more deatils. You have to add your phisics ettings, details about the problem, and what do you want clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the default collision detection shape is set to convex hull.

Changing it to mesh should solve your problem!

[image]